# how change the top left logo in admin back-end (dashboard) by code

Tags: backend

i am using Magento 2.2 and i want to change thee default Magento admin panel logo on the top left in admin backend, i have change the default for admin login page but it's not applicable for the admin top left logo

> can anyone give me any idea please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the admin logo image from the following file.

> vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml

There is an argument tag with `name="logo_image_src"`. You need to update your image file name here.

[image]

**Note:** Override the default.xml file in your admin theme before making this change.